# Positive-definite function on a group function on a group

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have quite a hard time understanding the definition of positive-definite functions that is based on Hilbert spaces, the one that I read from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group); it does not exactly specify that how $H$ relates to $G$? Or if the definition would makes sense for functions with compact support(for locally compact groups $G$) rather than a finite one. Can somebody clarify the formal definition please in this context?

Comment: 1.H is unrelated to G, you can even think of H as real or complex line in the first reading. 2. Replace the sum with integral (use Haar measure).

Comment: I think there are two camps when it comes to positive-definite functions (or functions of positive type). I prefer thinking of it in terms of integration. See Folland's *Abstract Harmonic Analysis*. He develops it there for functions in $L^{\infty}(G)$ but I think you can see how to do it in general. Rudin, surprisingly, is in the other camp (using sums).

Comment: @studiosus, $H$ in article refers to a Hilbert space and that is a functional space and needs a domain to be identified. What do you mean that $H$ to be real line? How can a Hilbert space be the real line?

Comment: Thanks @CameronWilliams. I cheked the definition in the book. There it there is no extra $H$ that appears on Wiki. And still I am quite confused to connect the two. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @Cupitor: Real line is a 1-dimensional real Hilbert space. Complex line is a complex Hilbert space (1-dimensional). I suggest you first work out the 1-dimensional case (the case of the real line), since it is the closest to the original notion of positive kernel. In this case, $L(H)$ is the same as ${\mathbb R}$. The 1-dimensional case is the one discussed in Folland's book.

Comment: Oh! You're right. Sorry for my misunderstanding. So I think I got it. $F(s^{-1}t)$ is a bounded function $h_{s,t}$ where its elementwise product with $h$ has an inner product with $h$ which its sums over different $s$ and $t$ should be positive. In case $L(H)$ is $\mathbb{R}$ the definition exactly coincides with positive definite kernels definitions. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to CameronWilliams I got the following definition from Folland's *Abstract Harmonic Analaysis*:
{{
A function of positive type on a locally compact group $G$ is a function $\phi\in L^{\infty}(G)$ that defines a positvie linear functional one the Banach *-algebra $L^1(G)$, i.e. that satisfies:
$$\forall f\in L^1{G}: \int (f^**f)\phi\geq0$$
We have:
$$\int (f^**f)\phi=\int\int\Delta(y^{-1})\bar{f(y^{-1})}f(y^{-1}x)\phi(x)dydx$$

so reversing the order of integration and substiuting $y^{-1}x$ for $x$ shows the $\phi$ is of positivre type if and only if
$$\int\int f(x)\bar{f(y)}\phi(y^{-1}x)dydx\geq 0.$$
}}

I can relate to the final equation but I still don't see where $H$ in wiki definition is coming from.